# Maximize JFrame unless monitor is a certain size?

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to maximize a JFrame below a certain resolution (up to and including 1024x768), but have the size fixed at that resolution if the monitor is larger?

I understand how .setExtendedState() works, but this only maximizes it regardless of monitor size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Toolkit's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) `getScreenSize()` method will allow you to get the screen's size.

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
System.out.println(screenSize); 
// use this information in a getPreferredSize() override.
```

This may be a case for overriding JFrame. For example,

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
   public static final int MAX_WIDTH = 0x400;
   public static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 0x300;

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
      int maxWidth = Math.min(screenSize.width, MAX_WIDTH);
      int maxHeight = Math.min(screenSize.height, MAX_HEIGHT);

      return new Dimension(maxWidth, maxHeight);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the screen size, and then make your decision accordingly.

Following is an example which demonstrates that:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MaximizedFrame
{
  private static final int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;
  private static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 768;

  public MaximizedFrame()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Maximized Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Dimension frameSize = screenSize;

    if (screenSize.width > MAX_WIDTH || screenSize.height > MAX_HEIGHT)
    {
      frameSize = new Dimension(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);
    }

    frame.setPreferredSize(frameSize);
    frame.setMinimumSize(frameSize);
    frame.setMaximumSize(frameSize);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        new MaximizedFrame();
      }
    });
  }
}
```